# wxWidget multiline notebook - cannot see 2nd line

Tags: wxwidgets

This code works perfectly

```
myNotebook = new wxNotebook( this, IDC_NOTEBOOK, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 500) );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 1" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 2" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 3" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 4" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 5" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 6" );
```

However, the tab names are so long and numerous they have to be horizontally scrolled.

Using the wxNB_MULTILINE style does not work properly: the second line of tabs is obscured and unreadable

```
myNotebook = new wxNotebook( this, IDC_NOTEBOOK, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(500, 500), wxNB_MULTILINE );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 1" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 2" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 3" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 4" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 5" );
myNotebook->AddPage( new wxNotebookPage( myNotebook, -1 ), L"TEST RECOMMENDATIONS 6" );
```

How do I use the multiline style correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found an elegant solution.  I need to force a refresh after resizing.

```
void MyFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent& )
{
    if( myNotebook ) {
        myNotebook->SetSize( GetClientRect() );
        myNotebook->Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After experimentation, I found this way:

Add one line, after all the AddPage() calls

```
    myNotebook->Layout();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the panel which holds the notebook page covers the second line of tabs.

I can force the panel to move out of the way by handling the `EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED` event and adding this line of code

```
myNotebook->GetPage( event.GetSelection() )->Move(0,40);
```

Ugly, but it does the job.